# Where is "containerEnvironment" in CloudKit? (Sandbox vs Production indicator)

Tags: cloudkit

The ToString() method of

```
  CKContainer.FromIdentifier("iCloud.com.My-Company").PrivateCloudDatabase
```

results in this string

```
<CKDatabase: 0x7ca335b0; databaseScope=Public, 
container=<CKContainer: 0x7fd630c0; 
containerID=<CKContainerID: 0x7ca33910; 
containerIdentifier=iCloud.com.getvalid.CloudKitAtlas, 
containerEnvironment="Sandbox">>>
```

I'm unable to locate "ContainerEnviornment" in any child or parent object.

Where is ContainerEnviornment located?

I want to have some custom logic behave one way in SandBox, another in Production.

Comment: What custom logic do you want to behave differently in the Development vs Production CloudKit environments? Generally speaking, this is not recommend and there may be another way to achieve your goals.

Comment: @breakingobstacles I want to expose a ViewController that exposes the CloudKit data, that otherwise could be a rejection for the app store, if Apple assumes that these GUIDs are as sensitive as the GameKit Guids, which are illegal according to the AppStore Guidelines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CloudKit container environment is determined at run-time using your app's `com.apple.developer.icloud-container-environment` entitlement.

There is no easy, built-in way to query this on any of the CloudKit objects.

If you'd like to browse your CloudKit data, you can use [CloudKit Dashboard](https://icloud.developer.apple.com/dashboard/).

If you want to display some additional/different data in your debug builds, you can detect whether your app is a debug or release build, and condition your debug-only display on that.

For Swift:

- Open your Target's **Build Settings** > **Swift Compiler - Custom Flags**.
- Add "`-DDEBUG`" to the Debug section under "**Other Swift Flags**".

Then, surround your Debug-only code with:

```
#if DEBUG
    // debug only code
#endif
```